# Foundation .large9 and columns

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation to build a website. 
And i have some problem with the nativ foundation columns system.
When i'm over 1047px width it's working but when i'm going under it the columns go full width. I can't get why and i'm sure it's pretty simple !

This i a website i'm currently working for school.
http://www.papaa.ch/tpi/bmpc.html

It occur on thoses pages at the moment. Some help would be lovely. I've searched around but i can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `small-9 columns`, that will give you the same layout regardless of the browser width. Right now you are only specifying 9 columns for large displays so when you get to the "medium" or "small" breakpoints they are defaulting back to 12 columns.

***edit*** you will also want to change `large-centered` to `small-centered` to make sure the columns stay centered.